# There is white space after my Navbar? How to delete it?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is my Navbar.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" id="Logo" href="/">xxxx</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="www.pinkman-translations.com/Sprachen">Sprachen</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="xxxx"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i>xxxx</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

After this, I set up a Section, but the problem is between the Navbar     and the Section there is some white space. I would like the Section to start right after the Navbar or even better the Navbar start at the top of the Section. Any Ideas?

Comment: Please provide more information and code that is actually able to be reproduced. You gave a lot of code that means nothing. We can't reproduce this issue or get enough context with the code you provided. That being said I would look into the margin and/or padding.

Comment: Sorry about that, it was my first post, My Question was answered, but next Time I will try to deliver a better Code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's `.navbar` component has a default bottom margin of 20px.  You can eliminate this by adding the following CSS to your stylesheet.

```
.navbar.navbar-default { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

I would recommend you review [Bootstrap's Navbar Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) as well, as you have a duplicate `.navbar` class in you unordered list within the `.navbar-collapse` `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to remove the white space:

```css
overflow: 'hidden'
```